# pyusb no obtiene el string del campo bcdUSB y devulve Љ

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente script cuya funcion es leer los datos del usb, pero al tratar de imprimir el campo string de esta propiedad: bcdUSB : 0x200 **USB 2.0** devuelve este simbolo **Љ**

este es el fragmento de codigo:

```
print(usb.util.get_string(device,device.bcdUSB)) #inea que no funciona
```

esto deveria de devolver **USB 2.0** pero devuelve esto:**Љ**

aqui esta el codigo completo:

```
import sys
import usb.core
import usb.util



dev1 = usb.core.find(find_all=True)
for device in dev1:
  for se in device:
    se = usb.core.find(idVendor = device.idVendor, idProduct=device.idProduct)
    if se._manufacturer is None:
      se._manufacturer=usb.util.get_string(se, se.iManufacturer)
      if se._manufacturer == 'Kingston':
        print(se._manufacturer)
        for cfg in device:
            #print(device)         #Toda la información del dispositivo
            print(usb.util.get_string(device,device.bcdUSB)) #inea que no funciona
            print(device.idVendor)
            print(device.idProduct)
            for intf in cfg:
                for ep in intf:
                    print(hex(ep.bEndpointAddress))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirando el código de `pyusb` vemos [aqui](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/blob/ffe6faf42c6ad273880b0b464b9bbf44c1d4b2e9/usb/util.py#L315) que la función `usb.util.get_string()` te devuelve la información como una cadena unicode, presuponiendo que la respuesta del dispositivo viene en UTF-16.

Esto, cuando tal información es realmente una cadena de texto, mostraría el texto correcto. Típicamente se usa `get_string()` para obtener la versión texto de ciertas propiedades, como el nombre del fabricante, etc.

En cambio `bcdUSB` no es una cadena, de acuerdo con lo que se explica [aquí](https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb5.shtml), sino un número de 16 bits cuyo significado sería (la traducción es mía):

> El campo bcdUSB informa de la versión de USB más alta soportada por el dispositivo. El valor está en BCD (Binary Coded Decimal), con un formato de 0xJJMN, donde JJ es el número mayor de versión, M es el número menor, y N es el número sub-menor. Por ejemplo, USB 2.0 es reportado como 0x0200, USB 1.1 como 0x0110 y USB 1.0 como 0x0100.

La forma de obtener ese dato no es llamar a `get_string()`, sino directamente leerlo de `device.bcdUSB` (e imprimirlo en `hex()`).

En tu caso, al pedírselo a `get_string()`, obtienes Љ. Una búsqueda revela que [Љ es el caracter Unicode U+0409](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0409). Por tanto el dispositivo te está respondiendo 0x0409. Esto no corresponden a un número de versión USB válido (Sería USB 4.0 que aún ni existe).

Más bien se trata del [descriptor de un Locale](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/0857a294-2598-4d6a-bb40-8e14396c28d2/what-is-0x0409-in-usbview-how-to-retrieve-this-string-information-in-kmdf-driver?forum=wdk), que representaría US English. De hecho, si imprimes los valores (en hex) de `device.langids` verás muy probablemente `0x409` (es lo que yo veo en mi sistema para todos mis dispositivos). El por qué el dispositivo responde esto no está claro, pero habida cuenta que le estás pidiendo la representación textual de una propiedad que no tiene tal representación, podemos suponer que el resultado es impredecible, o que la implementación de `pyusb` se lía y acaba retornándote el *locale* del dispositivo.

### Actualización

En respuesta a una pregunta del usuario en un comentario, proporciono una función que, recibiendo como parámetro el número de 16 bits obtenido con `device.bcdUSB`, devuelve una cadena tipo "USB 2.0".

La función opera con los bits del dato recibido, usando máscaras binarias y desplazamientos para extraer la información relevante y después formatearla como cadena.

```
def usb_version_string(bcd):
  major = (bcd & 0xFF00) >> 8
  minor = (bcd & 0x00F0) >> 4
  subminor = (bcd & 0x000F)
  return "USB {}.{}{}".format(major, minor, subminor or "")
```

Ejemplos de uso:

```
>>> print(usb_version_string(0x200))
USB 2.0
>>> print(usb_version_string(0x110))
USB 1.1
>>> print(usb_version_string(0x111))
USB 1.11
```

Comment: habara alguna manera de pasarlo a un diccionario o lista para imprimir el valor en forma de string, o tambien encotre esta funcion def find_descripto en la documentación que me señalaste pero no se si funcione

Comment: @Revsky01 Mira si la actualización de mi respuesta responde a lo que estabas buscando.